# .Net Winform (4.0) to Claims Based Auth CRM

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, wif, claims-based-identity

I have a custom Windows App (needs to be windows as it runs on a users machine and interfaces with TWAIN devices) which needs to communicate to a Claims Based Authenticated site.

What is the best way to achieve this?  Each user already has an account on the site which I want to use to authenticate with on the windows app.

Note: the site is actually a CRM2011 IF Deployment.

1. CRM 2011 setup

   - Cloud Hosted
   - Claims Based Authentication for IFD users
   - Windows (AD) Based Authentication for services (i.e. running on the same box) and workflows
2. STS setup is out of our control

Comment: Do you actually use the web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is CRM 2011 already configured to use a STS such as ADFS?

If so, you just need to add your app. to the STS as a Relying Party.

There's a [white paper](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3621).

Also, [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-wif-application-step-by-step-guide%28WS.10%29.aspx) gives a good overview of configuring ADFS and WIF in general.

Comment: Yes, its hosted on a third party supplier though so I think this will be a no go.